# Android changeBackground method not found

Tags: java, android, android-activity, methodnotfound

Android Studio: so I am very simply trying to change the background image of my active activity "Stream Page Main", which is not my main activity, by clicking on a button in this "Stream Page Main" activity. This should be one line of code, however, no matter what I try, I get a Method not Found Exception. Even if I try to change the background colour instead, it doesnt work.

```
public class StreamPageMain extends Activity {

public void changeBackgroundOfStreamPage(){

    StreamPageMain.this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.streaming_background_grey);

    //this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);

    //ConstraintLayout mConstraintLayout = (ConstraintLayout)findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout);
    //mConstraintLayout.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.streaming_background_grey);
}
}
```

On all of these three options I get the same Exception. The ID of my constraint Layout in the xml is constraintLayout and the button onclick is set to trigger the changeBackgroundOfStreamPage() method - there is no typo in there, I copied the name of the method.

No remarks from android studio within the code. I assume it has something to do with targeting the constraintLayout / the activity, but I do not see, why "this." doesn't do the trick...

this is the exception:

```
05-24 11:28:03.646 5776-5776/comn.example.ezio.streamingapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: comn.example.ezio.streamingapp, PID: 5776
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method changeBackgroundOfStreamPage(View) in the activity class comn.example.ezio.streamingapp.StreamPageMain for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button4'
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4015)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788)
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19896)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: changeBackgroundOfStreamPage [class android.view.View]
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:661)
at java.lang.Class.getMethod(Class.java:640)
at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:4008)
at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4788) 
at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19896) 
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5258) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:903) 
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:698)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming that you've assigned the callback to `button4` via View's `onClick` XML attribute. The callback for any button click listener has to conform to the following interface:

```
public static interface View.OnClickListener {

    abstract void onClick(View v);
}
```

So, you have to include parameter `View v` in your method, like this:

```
public void changeBackgroundOfStreamPage(View v) {

    StreamPageMain.this.findViewById(android.R.id.content).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.streaming_background_grey);

}
```

This can clearly be seen in the error that you've posted:

```
Could not find a method changeBackgroundOfStreamPage(View) in the activity class comn.example.ezio.streamingapp.StreamPageMain for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'button4'
```

Comment: Thank you, that is what I missed! Now it does not crash anymore and runs through the method, but the background stays unchanged - any ideas why?

Comment: That's most likely because of the id you're passing the the `findViewById` method. Try changing it to `findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout)` since you've mentioned that's the id of your layout in XML. Basically you need to pass the id of the container whose background you want to change.

Comment: Thank you again! My final code is  
public void changeBackgroundOfStreamPage(View v){
                this.findViewById(R.id.constraintLayout).setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.streaming_background_grey);
}